# Can a css menu do this?

Tags: css, menu

Is it possible to make a dropdown type menu navigation without using javascript and to show an image next to each items?

Also I would like to make this work with a table, so when you hover over a table cell, it would dropdown a list of links with an icon next to each one.  I am not sure if this is even possible without the use of javascript?

There is something similar to what I am trying to do on photobucket's menu
[alt text http://img2.pict.com/f9/72/7f/1437912/0/640/screenshot2b9.png](http://img2.pict.com/f9/72/7f/1437912/0/640/screenshot2b9.png)

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: A lot of people ask why no javascript, I don't mind using javascript I just want it to be very lightweight as my pages are getting heavier daily with javascript additions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible? **Yes**

Is it recommended? **No**

You still have to support IE6 and below which only supports the `:hover` pseudo-selector on `<a>` tags with an `href` attribute. Any other tag will have its `:hover` pseudo-selector ignored. For any other browser, you won't have that limitation.

By using the `<a>` tag, you are giving yourself the following limitations:

- No sub `<a>` tags, which means that the menu will basically lead to one place.
- No block level elements inside the `<a>` tag (which can be easily worked around by using `display: block` on inline elements. This means no `<div>` no `<table>` nor any other [block level elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Block_elements).

In a world without Internet Explorer 6 and below, this would rather be trivial to do. But considering that as of July 2009 [there is still 27.21% of the web using IE6](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2), you might not want to write them out.

Comment: data can be misleading. also, if everyone stops supporting IE6, maybe people will upgrade: www.browsesad.com

Comment: Try to tell that to corporations that have intranets used worldwide which only supports IE6. It simply ain't going to happen. As long as supporting IE6 has a monetary return (which it has, 1/4 of the internet population is using IE6), it won't disappear.

Comment: Campaigns like Browse Sad don't understand the mentality of corporate culture. I'll tell you the gold rule: change IS costly. And contrary of what these campaigns wants you to believe, in the end, the consumer has a negligible impact on the IT ecosystem.

Comment: if you aren't targeting the corporate culture, don't support IE6. also, people at work shouldn't be surfing the internet anyways ;)

Comment: Then you are also rejecting corporate customers, and corporate employees (who have machines provided by the business for home); which is a foolish move. Might be fine for a personal blog, but if you want to attract serious traffic, you will need to support it. But thanks Jason, your narrow-mindedness is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. If you look at the source for the page you'll see a `<ul>` making it work. They certainly use JS -in that I disabled JS in Firefox and then reloaded the page, at which point the menu ceased working- but I'm not sure how necessary that is to the menu itself.

You can show an image next to each menu item either by using an `<img />` tag in the (x)html or using a background-image in the css.

CSS-based approach:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
ul li {display: inline; position: relative;}

ul li ul {display: none; }

ul li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

ul li ul li {padding-left: 10px; background: #fff url(path-to-image.png) top left no-repeat; }
</style>

<ul>
<li>First item</li>
<li>Second item
    <ul>
        <li>Sub-level one</li>
        <li>Sub-level two</li>
    </ul></li>
<li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

(x)html based approach:

```
<style>... /* will still need to be styled according to your theme */ ...</style>

<ul>
<li><img src="menu-icon-1.png" alt="menu-icon" />First item</li>
<li><img src="menu-icon-2.png" alt="menu-icon" />Second item
    <ul>
        <li><img src="menu-icon-2-1.png" alt="menu-icon" />Sub-level one</li>
        <li><img src="menu-icon-2-2.png" alt="menu-icon" />Sub-level two</li>
    </ul></li>
<li><img src="menu-icon-3.png" alt="menu-icon" />Third item</li>
</ul>
```

If you want the menu items to have unique icons/images associated with them, then you'd have to use specific `id`s in the (x)html, so it's not particularly less, or more, convenient to use one approach in favour of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a menu using HTML and CSS only. But to handle all the **events** [keyboard and mouse ] you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Not if option is simply a link

Comment: I don't think you can handle keryboard events [up and down arrows] for a drop down like menu using CSS only. Sorry, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Lists are nothing more than `<li>` tags. Inside an `<li>` tag you can put whatever you want:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="alttext" />
       <p><a href="yourlink.html">Your link</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and then make your menu effect w/your CSS

**EDIT** ah, i see you only want to use tables. should have read more carefully. if you don't want to use javascript (why, i don't know), no, not w/css and html, at least not cross-browser. you can do it with the pseudoclass `:hover` which works for any element in modern browsers, but <IE6 won't know what to do with it. However, you should stop supporting IE6 anyways, so maybe you're ok :)

Comment: eventually I may switch away from tables, currently my header section uses some table cells, and only a couple of them need to have a drop down menu list, thats why I was saying tables, it would be easiar for me to add in, what I should do is find someone to help me convert my header to css

Answer (score 0):

Regarding support for IE6: 
Have a look at [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) it helps with a lot of issues with backwards compatibility, including the use of :hover on elements other than a. I've verified that it works with the CSS solution presented by ricebowl.

EDIT: The good thing about this script is that it is only used by IE5.5 and IE6 (and IE7 if you use the latest version). The latest version makes IE7 behave more like IE8 when rendering a page, making it easier to write simple and good HTML/CSS.